# Making user profiles without a database such as MySQL

Tags: database, user-profile

I have noticed some websites allow creating user profiles without a database such as MySQL, at least the wappalyzer does not detect it. How do they create such user profiles? Perhaps they create a file with the user details in it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For that to work the only real requirement is to be able to save some data, no matter how. A database is the typical approach, but by no means the only.

Besides that, a file on the server filesystem is possibly the easiest way. Just drop one on some folder and add lines to it when users register, and read and parse them when a user wants to login. This is, more or less, [how Unix-based systems store user accounts](http://www.catb.org/~esr/writings/taoup/html/ch05s01.html#id2901332), for example. Any website could use the same approach when it doesn't has much traffic.

Other options could be delegating the login work entirely. Things like OpenId or use a Facebook account for example. That way the site ask for account details to external sources, and are those who actually store that data, so your site would have no database at all. A webservice operated on another server is also a variation.

In short, the only requirement is to be able to store information in some way or another, and databases are just one option, but many other alternatives exist.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. So databases are an efficient way of handling a lot of data and traffic? Sorry if it seems like a noob question.

Comment: Problem with lot of traffic is concurrent access. When two processes write to the same file together, depending on how it's done, there is a risk of them overwriting each other or corrupting files if proper locking is not used. Databases take this into account and have lock and concurrency management clearly stablished with defined behavior. For read-only access files are probably fine however.